# How to Integrate Braintree to Dear Systems

Tags: api, e-commerce, braintree, integrate

Can Braintree can be integrated with Dear Systems? I would like to ask anyone to give me some advices, suggestions, documentations or sample of implementations on how to integrate BrainTree in Dear Systems.

Answer (score 0):

Dear Systems is an inventory management package.  Braintree is a payment processor.  So you would integrate *both* of those into an ecommerce platform (not one with the other).  For example, Dear has integrations with Shopify and Magento, as does Braintree.  So you'd want to pick and ecommerce system that has prebuilt integrations for both these components and go from there.

Here's Dear's integration page: 
http://dearsystems.com/inventory-software/partners/

and here's Braintree's: https://www.braintreepayments.com/features/third-party-integrations

(Although Braintree's list is only partial, since so many small e-commerce platforms have integrated with them.)